# Nested flatlist with array for JSON data - React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

Trying to display them as list item, date(2020-05-10,2020-05-22 etc...) as header and Hokey, Shopping under the date headers as list item.

```
{
   "2020-05-10":[
      {
         "title":"Hiking"
      },
      {
         "title":"Shopping"
      }
   ],
   "2020-05-22":[
      {
         "title":"Hiking"
      },
      {
         "title":"Football"
      }
   ],
   "2020-05-28":[
      {
         "title":"Hiking"
      },
      {
         "title":"Football"
      },
      {
         "title":"Cricket"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is totally incomprehensible. Where is the problem? What did you try that didn't work? A snippet of code, not only data, would be useful too.  Also probably not related to typescript, your question seems not to be about types.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<SectionList/>`

https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist

Similar to FlatList & ScrollView, but allows for sections (headers) and the presentation you need. You will have to map data differently, for example:

```
const sectionListData = [
 {
  sectionHeader: '22-05-2020',
  data: [{title: 'Football}, {title: 'Hockey'}]
 },
 ...
]
```